# PHP PDO Connection Efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, connection

I have an application that uses PDO to connect to it's relevant MySQL database. I call my connection string every time a request is made. Note I use prepared statements. My connection string method (dev version) looks like this...

```
protected function ConnectionString()
{

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".__DB_HOSTNAME.";dbname=".__DB_NAME, __DB_USERNAME, __DB_PASSWORD);

        return $dbh;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}
```

Recently my app's traffic has increased massively and I'm noticing that my app is failing to make a lot of connections. So the Catch is being triggered a lot more than normal. I assume this is because my app is not very efficient when connecting to the database.

Would it be wise for me to implement persistent connections? Or should I restructure my  code so less connections are requested. Or would this be a problem with the number of connections my MySQL databases allow? The max is currently set to 151, which I believe is the default.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't full application code... But it seems like for every single SQL query u make new connection.
If it so - u can realize **Singleton pattern** for DB connection.

Another way to decrease DB connections is to add DBH caching. Just store it in session and in next visit use already alive connection.

Comment: That's exactly the issue. I will look into the singleton pattern. How secure is the DBH Caching idea though?

Comment: While u are sure that session cookie isn't stolen - it is secure enough.